# Issue when trying to use fig, ax or plt.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

My following code is:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') #necessario para salvar figura no crontab
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


pathname = 'C:\\Users\\leo_v\\Desktop\\Nova_pasta\\leo_170818\lioc\\' 
pathnamep = 'C:\\Users\\leo_v\\Desktop\\Nova_pasta\\leo_170818\\avalia\\' 

prevs = np.sort(os.listdir(pathnamep))


rgp1 = pd.read_csv(pathnamep + prevs[-3] + '/PNBOIA_riogrande.txt',sep='\s*',
                     names=['ano','mes','dia','hora','minu','hs','tp','dp','spr'])

flp1 = pd.read_csv(pathnamep + prevs[-3] + '/PNBOIA_floripa.txt',sep='\s*',
                     names=['ano','mes','dia','hora','minu','hs','tp','dp','spr'])

sap1 = pd.read_csv(pathnamep + prevs[-3] + '/PNBOIA_santos.txt',sep='\s*',
                     names=['ano','mes','dia','hora','minu','hs','tp','dp','spr'])

rjp1 = pd.read_csv(pathnamep + prevs[-3] + '/PNBOIA_SIODOC.txt',sep='\s*',
                     names=['ano','mes','dia','hora','minu','hs','tp','dp','spr'])


vip1 = pd.read_csv(pathnamep + prevs[-3] + '/PNBOIA_vitoria.txt',sep='\s*',
                     names=['ano','mes','dia','hora','minu','hs','tp','dp','spr'])

rgp1['data'] = pd.to_datetime(rgp1.ano.astype(str) + '/' + rgp1.mes.astype(str) + '/' + rgp1.dia.astype(str) + '-' + rgp1.hora.astype(str) ,format="%Y/%m/%d-%H")
flp1['data'] = pd.to_datetime(flp1.ano.astype(str) + '/' + flp1.mes.astype(str) + '/' + flp1.dia.astype(str) + '-' + flp1.hora.astype(str) ,format="%Y/%m/%d-%H")
sap1['data'] = pd.to_datetime(sap1.ano.astype(str) + '/' + sap1.mes.astype(str) + '/' + sap1.dia.astype(str) + '-' + sap1.hora.astype(str) ,format="%Y/%m/%d-%H")
rjp1['data'] = pd.to_datetime(rjp1.ano.astype(str) + '/' + rjp1.mes.astype(str) + '/' + rjp1.dia.astype(str) + '-' + rjp1.hora.astype(str) ,format="%Y/%m/%d-%H")
vip1['data'] = pd.to_datetime(vip1.ano.astype(str) + '/' + vip1.mes.astype(str) + '/' + vip1.dia.astype(str) + '-' + vip1.hora.astype(str) ,format="%Y/%m/%d-%H")

rgp1 = rgp1.set_index('data')
flp1 = flp1.set_index('data')
sap1 = sap1.set_index('data')
rjp1 = rjp1.set_index('data')
#izp1 = izp1.set_index('data')
vip1 = vip1.set_index('data')

rgp1 = rgp1.ix[:,['hs','tp','dp','spr']]
flp1 = flp1.ix[:,['hs','tp','dp','spr']]
sap1 = sap1.ix[:,['hs','tp','dp','spr']]
rjp1 = rjp1.ix[:,['hs','tp','dp','spr']]
#izp1 = izp1.ix[:,['hs','tp','dp']]
vip1 = vip1.ix[:,['hs','tp','dp','spr']]

hoje = dt.datetime.strftime(dt.datetime.today(),'%Y%m%d')

tj = 15 * 24

plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{lmodern}"]
params = {'text.usetex' : True,
'font.size' : 11,
'font.family' : 'lmodern',
'text.latex.unicode': True,
}
plt.rcParams.update(params) 



plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{lmodern}"]
params = {'text.usetex' : True,
'font.size' : 14,
'font.family' : 'lmodern',
'text.latex.unicode': True,
}
plt.rcParams.update(params) 


u=1*np.sin(np.radians(sap1.dp-180))
v=1*np.cos(np.radians(sap1.dp-180))


plt.plot(sap1.hs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,9))
surf = ax.quiver(sap1.index.astype(np.int64)[::3],sap1.hs[::3],u[::3],v[::3],sap1.tp[::3],zorder=1)
ax.quiver(sap1.index.astype(np.int64)[::3],sap1.hs[::3],u[::3],v[::3],edgecolor='k', facecolor='None', linewidth=.5)
ax.plot(sap1.index.astype(np.int64),sap1.hs,'gray',linewidth=3,zorder=0)
ax.grid(), ax.set_ylabel('Significant Wave Height (m)');ax.set_ylim([0,8])
cbar=fig.colorbar(surf,orientation='vertical')
cbar.set_label(label='Peak Period (s)',size=14)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)
```

The main objective of this code is obtain someting like this image (but the x axis should be dates instead days of week):

[image]

For some reason that I can't understand when I try to use plt.plot or fig, ax returns me this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

The entire code is running well, all my variables are working. The only problem is when I try to use specifically `plt.plot()` or `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,9))`

I'm using python 3.6 on Windows 10 machine.

Would be thankful if someone could help.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [mcve], without the external files?

Comment: This image that I added should be the result from my script

Answer (score 0):

To me, the same problem arised. The old-fashion restart of Python solved the problem. Restarting the kernel was in my case not enough, but a full restart did the job (I use the Spyder platform, which I restarted).